What does the standard deviation of TIE measurement tell me about my clock signal jitter?
When we take a Time Interval Error (TIE) measurement of a clock signal, we are presented with two measurement outputs, the mean error and the standard deviation. When I  measured the TIE of a 32.768kHz clock signal from the output of a oscillator, I get the following values, 30ps mean error and a standard deviation of 240us. The standard deviation seems rather high, and I can not determine whether this is a measurement error or real. Regardless, how do I quantify the effect of the standard deviation over time, say after 1 year what is the drift/error can I expect?
Additional Information:

Measurement was taken for 160ms
Measured stability was -3ppm whereas spec was +/-20ppm


You don't provide enough info to say what you can expect a year from now.

So based on the information provided, you are suggesting that the question is unanswerable. Then what additional informational can I provide? Note I am very new to jitter measurements in general, so any guidance is appreciated.

As a minimum, you need to specify the measurement period.

Is this oscillator free-running? Is it locked? Is it using a crystal? TIE is a highpass filtered version of your jitter, so it is impossible to comment on the values without knowing the measurement details and clock signal origin.
